# Does azure assign a different subnet or IP to each web App?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Hi I'm trying to make 400 web apps using azure services but the apps have to be off different subnets at least. In other words, I don't want to apps to share the same IP with the same subnet. So How can I do that? And how does Azure help in these situations

Comment: Hi Hasan can you give me more detail into what you are trying to accomplish with this app?

Comment: I'm trying to use the IP kind of as a proxy to monitor sites for latest products so I want to eventually deploy 400 web apps eventually on the condition that two web apps cant share the same IPs with the same subnet. In my case, how many instances and IPs should I get/reserve to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2):

You can use IP based SSL certificates to ensure each URL has a unique IP.  [(see documentation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-ssl#bind-your-ssl-certificate-1)

Each App Service Plan has a limit of 10 Web Apps and IP based SSL certificates so you would likely need 40 App Service Plans. You may run into an account wide limit on the number of static IPs you can claim. Possible solutions to this would be to contact customer support to get your quota increased or use multiple Azure subscriptions.